# How can I do a Ctrl+Click on protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, protractor, end-to-end

I have tried weird combination as the following, but none of them are working:

```
var ptor = protractor.getInstance();
ptor.actions().mouseMove(node).keyDown(ptor.Key.CTRL).sendKeys(ptor.Key.CLICK).perform();
```

Comment: Define "not working". What isn't working? What do you want it to do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to chain `mouseMove()`, `keyDown()` and `click()`:

```
var elm = element(by.id('my_id'));

browser.actions()
    .mouseMove(elm)
    .keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL)  // COMMAND for Mac 
    .click()
    .perform();
```

Tested it on Chrome by clicking on a link - opens up a link in a new tab.

---

Note that, starting with protractor 1.5, there is a global `browser` object that should be used instead of `protractor.getInstance()`, see [Breaking Changes](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes).

Comment: Thank you! As a comment, in protractor 1.2, CTRL key throws the following error (- Error: Not a modifier key)
and SHIFT key works correctly.
protractor.getInstance().actions().mouseMove(node).keyDown(protractor.Key.SHIFT).click().perform();

Comment: @Chexpir FYI the CTRL key (under Windows) is named protractor.Key.CONTROL