# How to perform Control+Click on a multi-select option in protractor?

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I'm trying to click on multiple selections in a multi select box. But I'm unable to perform the same.

What i have tried so far:

```
let input = $('input');
let option1 = input.all(by.cssContainingText('option','One'));
let option2 = input.all(by.cssContainingText('option','Two'));
option1.click();
browser.actions().mouseMove(option2).keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).click().perform();
```

This solution is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27832799/8558515) but it throws an error: `unknown error: at least an element or offset should be set`. It also shows `Promise rejection was handled asynchronously` in browser.pause() logs while the click event is invoked.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to solve this issue.
For some reason the method I used to select options were not working. So I modified the code to use `element` based locator in a different way.

```
let options = $$('multiselect-dropdown option');
options.get(0).click();
browser.actions()
    .mouseMove(options.get(1))
    .keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL)
    .click()
    .keyUp(protractor.Key.CONTROL)
    .perform();
```

Now everything's working fine.